# Run MVC project with Visual Studio 2015 on a dedicated server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging, remote-server, dedicated-hosting

I have a dedicated server on a datacenter which a domain (ronako.ir) is connected to. I have visual studio 2015 update 3 on the server for creating a website. I'd like when I run the mvc projct on vs 2015 on debug mode the browser start it on http://ronako.ir May anyone please help me how to do that? If you want any more details about my dedicated server let me know.

Thanks id advance

Comment: You can configure Web Application projects to connect to full-fat IIS (instead of IIS Express), do this on the Web tab. Note you need IIS debugging enabled and there might be DCOM permissions to contend with.

Comment: Thanks. But how to enable IIS Debugging?

Comment: In menu - DEBUG -> Attach to process or press alt + ctrl + p - you will see a list of processes - find w3p.exe and press attach button. Please note you have to run visual studio as administrator